# Why I can't see .rc files in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator

I have an open-source project successfully compiled using **Qt Creator** on a **Ubuntu (Trusty)** OS which I am trying to customize.

The problem is that even if in the project itself (on my machine) I can see `.rc` files, in the Qt tree view those files doesn't appear.

Why is this happening and how can I modify / add those `.rc` files to my project ? There are probably more than 100 resource files so adding them manually (if possible) is not a solution.

---

**UPDATE 1:**
I can't seem to find it

[image: tree_view]

**As an important note**, you should know that this is just an **imported project** which is compiled / built & runned using QT Creator.

Comment: Are they in your .pro file? Or are you using cmake, qbs, etc.?

Comment: @cmannett85 what `.pro` file ? As an idea, I am trying to change chromium. Tell me from where to get the information you need and I'll answer. (am new to Qt - have used something else )

Comment: It's your project file, you should be able to see it in the project tree view.

Comment: @cmannett85 I have updated the question. I can't seem to find any .pro file

Comment: So it's not a Qt project then. You'll probably have to manually add them to chromium.files - you might be able to use wildcards to automate it.

Comment: @cmannett85 do you have time to add an answer explaining how to do this ?

Comment: I have no idea if that'll work, I was just guessing. Experiment by manually adding one .rc file and see if it appears in the tree view as you expected.

Comment: @cmannett85 it works. However, I will try to make a python script to get all the files and copy & paste them there. But you can add a solution as I want to learn this

Comment: @cmannett85 if the project is not originally created with Qt Creator, is there any way of adding a .pro which includes what I need ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `.pro` includes something like

```
OTHER_FILES += your_file_name.rc
```

as with any other file, you must reference those files in the project file to include them. Of course, this will only *show* `your_file_name.rc` in the tree view.

Comment: please see the update. I do not find any `.pro` file

Comment: if the project is not originally created with Qt Creator, is there any way of adding a .pro which includes what I need ?